# Different Timer object for new Task?

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I use

```
timer.schedule(new DoReassignement(), delay, controlInterval);
```

And want to add

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(fetchMail, getTomorrowMorning4am(), fONCE_PER_DAY);
```

Should I use different Timer object for new task or I shouldnt ? Thanks in advance.

Edit: my tasks sometimes could be(and should be) executed at the same time, but I dont want for each of them to delay or wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule multiple tasks on the timer. Each task is run by the same timer thread though, so the tasks should be short. If they're not, they can back up the timer.

Comment: What means 'back up the timer' ?

Comment: The tasks might get slowed down. If you have 1 really long task running, the other ones cannot run until that one finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse a timer for multiple tasks. It'll only throw an `IllegalStateException` if you attempt to schedule the same task 2x

[**See the `scheduleAtFixedRate`** documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)